# Solve doesn't produce a solution, although one exists

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve the following system of equations:

$c (\alpha+\beta \gamma)=\alpha x, c(\gamma\alpha+\beta)=-\beta x$

with respect to $x$ ($\alpha, \beta,\gamma,c \in \mathrm{R}$)

The solution is easy to work by hand and is $x=\pm c \sqrt{1-\gamma^2}$

Now I try:

```
Solve[c (α + β γ) == α x && 
c (γ α + β) == -β x, x]
(* output *)
{}
```

no output, so I explicitly state that $\alpha, \beta,\gamma,c \in \mathrm{R}$

```
Solve[c (α + β γ) == α x && 
c (γ α + β) == -β x, 
x /; Element[α | β | γ | c | x, Reals]]
(* output *)
{}
```

again no output. As a final try I give the constraint $\gamma^2 < 1$ (although that shouldn't be necessary):

```
Solve[c (α + β γ) == α x && 
c (γ α + β) == -β x, x /; γ^2 < 1]
(* output *)
{}
```

no luck either. What am I missing?

Comment: Tow equations for one variable do not have a general solution. There is a solution only for specific values of the parameters. You may  try "Reduce" to find these special solutions.

Comment: You provided two equations and ask for one unknown, so your unknown is overdetermined.  Solving the first equation gives $x = c(1+\beta \gamma / \alpha)$ while solving the second equation gives $x = - c(1 + \gamma \alpha / \beta)$.  These are not identical (unless you've got more information than you've shared) so the solution set is empty.  But given what you claim the answer is I suspect you've got more information.  For example, try `Solve[c (\[Alpha] + \[Beta] \[Gamma]) == \[Alpha] x && 
  c (\[Gamma] \[Alpha] + \[Beta]) == -\[Beta] x, {x, \[Gamma]}]`

Comment: @evanb This is an intermediate step of a larger calculation, actually $\alpha, \beta$ are also to be determined, after $x$ has been found

Comment: @DanielHuber thanks for the comment, I also tried `Reduce` but didn't get the desired output

Comment: @geom the point is: now is the time to determine one of alpha, beta, or gamma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also succeed by solving the two equations one after the other,for instance begin with the second and solve for a or b like

```
Solve[c (a + b g) == a x /. (Solve[{c (b + a g) == -b x}, a]) // 
Evaluate, x]
(* {{x -> -Sqrt[c^2 - c^2 g^2]}, {x -> Sqrt[c^2 - c^2 g^2]}} *)
```

Comment: I was just thinking that :). Thanks

Answer (score 3):

when you have less equations than the number of variables and want to solve for one variable, then if you gives all the variables to solve, it will do it and give all possible solutions

```
eq1 = c (α + β γ) == α x;
eq2 = c (γ α + β) == -β x;

sol = Solve[{eq1, eq2}, {x, α, c , β , γ, α}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you pick the 3rd solution and do couple of manipulations, you will get what you want with assumption that α > 0

```
 solB = Solve[γ == -((    2 α β)/(α^2 + β^2)), β]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And now

```
Solve[FullSimplify[x == (c (α^2 - β^2))/(α^2 + β^2) /. #, 
    Assumptions -> α > 0], x] & /@ solB
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I do not know if there is a more direct way to do this., May be someone knows.